swift_isUniquelyReferenced_nonNull_native causes random and systematic crash on iOS 17.x
In my app, a crash occurs only on iOS 17.xx versions when I establish a BLE connection to a peripheral, scan wifi networks and connect to one of them via BLE.
private func writeData(writingMode: String) {
    
        guard let discoveredPeripheral = discoveredPeripheral,
                let transferCharacteristic = transferCharacteristic
            else { return }
        
        // check to see if number of iterations completed and peripheral can accept more data
  
            let mtu = discoveredPeripheral.maximumWriteValueLength (for: .withoutResponse)
            var rawPacket = [UInt8]()

            if( self.connected && !self.wifiScanDone){
                self.data.append(0x20)
                self.data.append(0x04)
                self.data.append(0x00)
                self.data.append(0x00)
                self.data.append(0x03)
                self.data.append(0x47)
                self.data.append(0x02)
                self.data.append(0x10)
                self.data.append(0x00)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0x56) }
        
            else if (self.connected && self.wifiScanDone) {
                self.data.append(0x20)
                self.data.append(0x04)
                self.data.append(0x00)
                self.data.append(0x00)
                self.data.append(0x03)
                self.data.append(0x47)
                self.data.append(0x03)
                self.data.append(0x10)
                self.data.append(0x00)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0xff)
                self.data.append(0x57)
                }
                print("writing data", String(describing: self.data))
        
            let bytesToCopy: size_t = min(mtu, self.data.count)
            self.data.copyBytes(to: &rawPacket, count: bytesToCopy)
            var packetData = Data(bytes: &rawPacket, count: bytesToCopy)

            let stringFromData = String(data: packetData, encoding: .utf8)
            os_log("Writing %d bytes: %s", bytesToCopy, String(describing: stringFromData))
            
            discoveredPeripheral.writeValue(packetData, for: transferCharacteristic, type: .withResponse)
            
            packetData.removeAll()
            self.data.removeAll()
            
            discoveredPeripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: transferCharacteristic)
            self.writeIterationsComplete += 1
        
    
        if writeIterationsComplete == defaultIterations {
            // Cancel our subscription to the characteristic
        }
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        
        let wifiSelectionController = segue.destination as? WifiSelectionTestViewController
       
        if segue.identifier == "skipSegue" {
            if EcojokoHelper.isEcojokoV2() {
                
                 wifiSelectionController?.wifiNetworksFromBle = wifiNetworks
              
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    private func writeDataScanDone() {
        
        guard let discoveredPeripheral = discoveredPeripheral,
              let transferCharacteristic = transferCharacteristic
        else { return }
        
        // check to see if number of iterations completed and peripheral can accept more data
            let mtu = discoveredPeripheral.maximumWriteValueLength (for: .withResponse)
            var rawPacket = [UInt8]()
            
            self.data.append(0x20)
            self.data.append(0x04)
            self.data.append(0x00)
            self.data.append(0x00)
            self.data.append(0x03)
            self.data.append(0x47)
            self.data.append(0x03)
            self.data.append(0x10)
            self.data.append(0x00)
            self.data.append(0xff)
            self.data.append(0xff)
            self.data.append(0xff)
            self.data.append(0xff)
            self.data.append(0xff)
            self.data.append(0xff)
            self.data.append(0xff)
            self.data.append(0xff)
            self.data.append(0xff)
            self.data.append(0xff)
            self.data.append(0x57)
            
            
            let bytesToCopy: size_t = min(mtu, self.data.count)
            self.data.copyBytes(to: &rawPacket, count: bytesToCopy)
            var packetData = Data(bytes: &rawPacket, count: bytesToCopy)
            
            let stringFromData = String(data: packetData, encoding: .utf8)
            os_log("Writing  scan mode  %d bytes: %s", bytesToCopy, String(describing: stringFromData))
            
            discoveredPeripheral.writeValue(packetData, for: transferCharacteristic, type: .withResponse)
            
            packetData.removeAll()
            self.data.removeAll()
            
            discoveredPeripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: transferCharacteristic)
            self.writeIterationsComplete += 1
            self.centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(discoveredPeripheral)
            self.cleanup()
            print("**** AT THIS POINT THE WIFI SCAN IS DONE ")
            self.scanWritingData = true
            if (self.connected && self.wifiScanDone && self.wifiNames.count == self.wifiCount &&  self.fillListDone) {
                
                if let centralManager = self.centralManager {
                    centralManager.stopScan()
                    // os_log("Scanning stopped")
                }
                self.data.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            }
    }
    

    /*
     *  If the connection fails for whatever reason, we need to deal with it.
     */
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        os_log("Failed to connect to %@. %s", peripheral, String(describing: error))
        cleanup()
    }
    
    /*
     *  We've connected to the peripheral, now we need to discover the services and characteristics to find the 'transfer' characteristic.
     */
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        if( !wifiListing)
        {
            print("**** BEFORE CONNECTION ***** The available peripherals are : \(String(describing: peripheral.services))")
            os_log("Peripheral Connected")
            self.connected = true
            
            // Stop scanning
            self.centralManager.stopScan()
            os_log("Scanning stopped")
            
            connectionIterationsComplete += 1
            writeIterationsComplete = 0
            
            // Clear the data that we may already have
           // data.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            
            // Make sure we get the discovery callbacks
            peripheral.delegate = self
            
            // Search only for services that match our UUID
            peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
           
        }
    }

# Crashlytics - Stack trace
# Platform: apple
# Version: 1.1 (1.9)
# Issue: 412239cf1ac3c946eb36a0f8fcd03787
# Session: 411b37f768814760898b918fa9d8c1b3_DNE_0_v2
# Date: Wed Apr 17 2024 08:14:28 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)

com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1af8 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1890 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x17a8 mach_msg_overwrite + 436
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x15e8 mach_msg + 24
4  CoreFoundation                 0x3601c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5  CoreFoundation                 0x33f04 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6  CoreFoundation                 0x33968 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7  GraphicsServices               0x34e0 GSEventRunModal + 164
8  UIKitCore                      0x22aedc -[UIApplication _run] + 888
9  UIKitCore                      0x22a518 UIApplicationMain + 340
10 Vattenfall                     0xb4ec main + 20 (AppDelegate.swift:20)
11 ???                            0x1b33d6d84 (Manquant)

com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1af8 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1890 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x17a8 mach_msg_overwrite + 436
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x15e8 mach_msg + 24
4  CoreFoundation                 0x3601c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5  CoreFoundation                 0x33f04 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6  CoreFoundation                 0x33968 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7  Foundation                     0x2b4a8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
8  Foundation                     0x554e8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 64
9  UIKitCore                      0x18dac8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 420
10 Foundation                     0x9ca9c __NSThread__start__ + 732
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x2a90 _pthread_start + 136
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1fcc thread_start + 8

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
0  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x1ef18 FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 184
1  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x1f2f8 FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1176
2  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x16598 FIRCLSHandler + 48
3  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x18d58 FIRCLSMachExceptionServer + 688
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x2a90 _pthread_start + 136
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1fcc thread_start + 8

com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1af8 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1890 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x17a8 mach_msg_overwrite + 436
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x15e8 mach_msg + 24
4  CoreFoundation                 0x3601c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5  CoreFoundation                 0x33f04 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6  CoreFoundation                 0x33968 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7  CFNetwork                      0x25ac48 estimatedPropertyListSize + 38228
8  Foundation                     0x9ca9c __NSThread__start__ + 732
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x2a90 _pthread_start + 136
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1fcc thread_start + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xa084 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1f6c _pthread_wqthread + 364
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1fc0 start_wqthread + 8

Crashed: ZuluCalendar
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x4065e4 swift_isUniquelyReferenced_nonNull_native + 48
1  Foundation                     0x2e75c specialized Set._Variant.insert(_:) + 204
2  Foundation                     0x2e8de4 _fromNSCalendarUnits(_:) + 176
3  Foundation                     0x2e410 _NSSwiftCalendar._components(_:from:) + 60
4  Foundation                     0x2e274 @objc _NSSwiftCalendar._components(_:from:) + 80
5  CoreFoundation                 0xc4e08 CFCalendarDecomposeAbsoluteTime + 348
6  Security                       0x11df64 __SecAbsoluteTimeGetGregorianDate_block_invoke + 64
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x3dd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x132c4 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
9  Security                       0xaf0c SecCFCalendarDoWithZuluCalendar + 128
10 Security                       0x7ad4 der_encode_generalizedtime_body_repair + 232
11 Security                       0x76ac der_encode_plist_repair + 468
12 Security                       0x7560 der_encode_plist_repair + 136
13 Security                       0x7560 der_encode_plist_repair + 136
14 Security                       0x740c add_sequence_to_array + 136
15 CoreFoundation                 0x2507c -[__NSDictionaryM __apply:context:] + 128
16 Security                       0x13b80 der_encode_dictionary_repair + 124
17 Security                       0x740c add_sequence_to_array + 136
18 CoreFoundation                 0x2507c -[__NSDictionaryM __apply:context:] + 128
19 Security                       0x13b80 der_encode_dictionary_repair + 124
20 Security                       0x7560 der_encode_plist_repair + 136
21 Security                       0x740c add_sequence_to_array + 136
22 CoreFoundation                 0x2507c -[__NSDictionaryM __apply:context:] + 128
23 Security                       0x13b80 der_encode_dictionary_repair + 124
24 Security                       0xcc2c CFPropertyListCreateDERData + 100
25 Security                       0xcb78 SecTrustSerialize + 216
26 CFNetwork                      0x1ef68 _CFNetworkSetHSTSStoragePath + 93612
27 CFNetwork                      0xab3ac CFURLDownloadStart + 74768
28 CFNetwork                      0xaaedc CFURLDownloadStart + 73536
29 CFNetwork                      0xbc780 CFURLDownloadStart + 145380
30 CFNetwork                      0x1da190 CFHTTPCookieStorageUnscheduleFromRunLoop + 158916
31 CFNetwork                      0xbaa64 CFURLDownloadStart + 137928
32 libboringssl.dylib             0x3b638 __boringssl_context_evaluate_trust_async_external_block_invoke + 448
33 libdispatch.dylib              0x213c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
34 libdispatch.dylib              0x3dd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
35 libdispatch.dylib              0xb400 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748
36 libdispatch.dylib              0xbf64 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 432
37 libdispatch.dylib              0xd284 _dispatch_workloop_invoke + 1756
38 libdispatch.dylib              0x16cb4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288
39 libdispatch.dylib              0x16528 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404
40 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1f20 _pthread_wqthread + 288
41 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1fc0 start_wqthread + 8


First, the code establishes a BLE connection to a specific peripheral, when he finds the right services and characteristics, it connects to them and asks the device to do a wifi scan. Then, the device searches for nearby wifi networks and sends the list to the app. The user selects one of the listed networks, fills the password and sends a connection request to the BLE peripheral.
Here is the crash's stacktrace from Crashlytics. I'd like to get some help resolving the crash:
Sample code of BLE Exchange source code: (can't provide full source code due to security and privacy compliance) :

You mention swift_release_dealloc in the title, but I cannot see that function anywhere in the crash report. What makes you think that it is the culprit?

That's the problem: The stacktrace doesn't show the function/ instruction causing the crash, it just mentions that swift_release_dealloc (which is a core swift function) is responsible for the crash.

Why do you use self.data instead of a local array?  Swift arrays are not thread safe.  Using a property looks like a recipe for problems

I've updated the code and excluded global arrays (self.data) but nothing changed, the app crashes too. Instead, I am wondering why is it only happening on iOS17 versions? As far I know, if the crash occurs on specific iOS versions, it means that is caused by a third-party component or library and not by source code anomalies.

Your crash message seems to indicate a calendar operation as a result of a download task, but you need a proper symbolicated crash log file otherwise you are just guessing.

As far as I am aware, there is no download task in my code. But, maybe Alamofire, Firebase or other libraries (pods) do similar operations in their core components.
